# Nested Array in Json- c# and .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, json, .net

I am trying to have a json file using c# like this

```
{
  "name" :{
       "firstname": "john",
       "lastname": "Doe" 
   },
   "age":{
       "real": "2",
       "dogyears": "22"
   },
   "boo":{
        "foo":[
           "bar",
           "haa",
           "haha"
         ]
   }
}
```

And my class looks like this- I do not know if this is right -

```
    public class data
    {
        public string[] name { get; set; }
        public string[] age { get; set; }
        public string[] boo {get; set;}
    }
```

Is there something more that I need to add to the class?

Also, here is how I am trying to write this into an external json file

```
String first_name= firstN.Text;
String last_name=lastN.Text;
....
List<data> dataa = new List<data>();
        dataa.Add(new data()
        {
            //I am not sure what goes here - probably something like this
            firstname = first_name;

        });
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataa.ToArray());

        //write string to file
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(JsonFilePath, json);
```

I am new- so any help would be greatly appreciated thanks :)

Comment: All root properties are *objects*, not arrays. Only `boo.foo` is a `string[]` array

Comment: You can have Visual Studio generate the necessary classes by copying the JSON string and paste it into a source file using `Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes`

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you meant. can you please elaborate?

Comment: [Paste JSON/XML As Classes in Visual Studio](https://medium.com/@coffmans/paste-json-xml-as-classes-in-visual-studio-66e67e60be44)

Comment: Thank you. That is good info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panagiotis has commented about the very useful "paste json as classes" feature, but I've typically preferred using something like http://QuickType.io because it generates a bit more feature complete/useful/name-compliant set of classes:

```
// <auto-generated />
//
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using Leia;
//
//    var data = Data.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace Leia
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public Name Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("age")]
        public Age Age { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("boo")]
        public Boo Boo { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Age
    {
        [JsonProperty("real")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Real { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dogyears")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Dogyears { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Boo
    {
        [JsonProperty("foo")]
        public string[] Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Name
    {
        [JsonProperty("firstname")]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastname")]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Data
    {
        public static Data FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json, Agarwal.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Data self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Agarwal.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }

    internal class ParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(long) || t == typeof(long?);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
            var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
            long l;
            if (Int64.TryParse(value, out l))
            {
                return l;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type long");
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (untypedValue == null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
                return;
            }
            var value = (long)untypedValue;
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
            return;
        }

        public static readonly ParseStringConverter Singleton = new ParseStringConverter();
    }
}
```

Go to http://quicktype.io and paste your json in, set your options. The end

I have no affiliation with that service. Plenty of others may be found by using a web search like "json to c#"

---

How you might use it:

The C# looks a lot like the JSON:

```
String first_name= firstN.Text;
String last_name=lastN.Text;

Data d = new Data(){
   Name = new Name(){ FirstName = first_name, LastName = last_name }
};

string json = d.ToJson();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(JsonFilePath, json);
```

Comment: NVM, this is great! I love this tool. Thank you so much :)